# ImageView showing up in debug mode, but not in run mode

Tags: android

My case is a little special.... I'm trying to get an image via tcp and make it show into my device screen.

Please, don't ask me to do it with another kind of way to get the image, since this is the only way i can do it, and that's not my issue.

What happens is that when i'm debuging step-by-step my program, the image shows up into my screen. But when i run it without debuging, it doesn't show up.

This is my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) // Aquesta funcio es crida al començar, pero tambe cada vegada que es gira la pantalla.
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("ip-here", port-here);

            DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] bSize = new byte[10];
            while(bytesRead < 10){
                bytesRead += ins.read(bSize, 0, 10 - bytesRead);
            }
            String sSize = new String(bSize);
            Integer size = Integer.valueOf(sSize);

            byte[] pic = new byte[size];
            bytesRead = 0;
            while(bytesRead < size){
                bytesRead += ins.read(pic, 0, size - bytesRead);
            }

            Bitmap bitmapimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pic, 0, bytesRead);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmapimage);

            tv.setText(sSize + " -> #" + size + "# -> #" + bytesRead + "#");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tv.setText("error de IO");
        }
    }
}
```

Additional information:
The TCP server sends a 10-char string containing the size of the image (in base 10). And then the whole image in jpg format.

As you can see, i put a Textbox to tell me what's happening, and it's ok. Even when i run it, it says he got the whole image, but it just doesn't show up...

Am i missing something? maybe i shouldn't put this code in the onStart() method?

Thank you,
Víctor

Comment: Does the `bitmapimage` variable have a value? If it's null (decoder failure), I think everything will still "work" but you'll have no image.

Comment: indeed, it's value it's null... and it's not about debugging/running mode, but it looks like it has to wait some time before reading the socket... Putting a Thread.sleep(1000) right after connecting to server (new Socket(...)) it works fine...

Comment: It looks like it's a network problem... I watched the byte[] pic array. If the program waits, he gets - let's say - 1 2 3 4 5. If it doesn't wait, it gets 5 4 2 X X (i.e. disordered and missing 2 parts, the 2 parts missing are just all zeros). Doesn't TCP ensure that all packets will be recieved and in the right order? Why does it have to do about waiting a second after connecting or not?

Comment: My bad... resolved... it was on this line: "bytesRead += ins.read(pic, 0, size - bytesRead);"... i had to put "bytesRead += ins.read(pic, bytesRead, size - bytesRead);", else i was writing on the same position each time i get something. Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: Sorry for not responding (blame the Oscars), but yes, I assumed something was wrong with the read rather than the decoding. Good thing you fixed it.